# Clock Recovery for 4FSK Modulation in GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio

I have made a loopback flowgraph in GNU Radio companion to implement a 4FSK modulation. For the modulation section, I have simply adjusted the "chunks to symbol" block to map each 2 incoming bits onto a 4-ary constellation: "-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5" and then a frequency modulator does the rest of the job.

For the demodulation process however, I came up with a configuration based on the performance of the Quadrature Demod block. This block returns the values -1.5, -0.5, 0.5 and 1.5 in correspondence with each frequency tone that has been sent to it. I made four sets of 2 Threshold blocks, 2 Multiply constant blocks and 1 Add block. Each set covers the region around a symbol in the constellation. The four regions are: -2 to -1 for -1.5, -1 to 0 for -0.5, 0 to 1 for 0.5 and 1 to 2 for 1.5. When QDemod block returns a value of -1.2 (for example), the lowest set returns a 1 while the other 3 sets are zero. These zeros and the one add together, 1 is subtracted from the result and a zero is demodulated (equivalent for bits: 00).

This flowgraph works fine. I can hear the music without any problem. But, as you know, I need a clock recovery to send and receive in this way in reality. Well, previously, I had successfully implemented a BFSK system using M&M clock recovery. However, that block does not work here and I don't know why. The input to M&M clock recovery here is a PAM signal with 4 levels, similar to its input in BFSK system with but with 2 level. But I don't know why it corrupts my signal here.

Can you please help me find out why M&M doesn't work here? Do you have any suggestion for me to do synchronization task? Thank you in advance.

I have attached my loopback flowgraph in 2 pictures below. I couldn't fit it into one picture.
[image: First Pic]

[image: Second Pic]

Comment: This is a very old version of GNU Radio. If you update to something less ancient, you get a very much better symbol synchronization block.

Comment: Thank you very much MR. Müller for your response. So you mean if I update my GRC, M&M block will work fine here too? Is that all the problem?

Comment: And also my GRC version is 3.7.13.4. Which version would be enough and is more stable to achieve that quality in synchronization I need? Do you recommend 3.9 version? Well, I had a hard time installing this current version. Finally, I used the instructions on Ettus website and 3.7.13.4 was the latest version in the instructions on that website. Therefore, if I need to update, I will need instructions on how to do it. Can you please give me a link to verified instructions for upgrading grc to the appropriate version? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Don't follow the instructions on third party websites. gnuradio.org is the site with installation instructions. On modern Linux, OS X or windows, installation is really easy. No, you don't get a better M&M, you get a better alternative.

Comment: Ok. I will try to update it. Can you please tell me what would be the alternative? I think after the update, this would be my question, if you do me this favor, too. I want to know what I have to look for in the updated GRC. Thanks.

Comment: the "symbol sync" block in GNU Radio 3.8.2.0 or later is great.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @rclocher3 Hello and Thank you!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hello again, excuse me, I have updated my GRC to version 3.8.2. In the past day, I tested many values for the parameters of the symbol synch block. I see I first have to choose the type of TED, each of which has its own requirements on the input, similar to the TED constellation slicer. At this stage, I'm confused and even doubt if this block can work for me, because I am not using any pulse shaping filter for my symbols. My baseband signal (the symbols) is a PAM4 signal since it is 4-level FSK. The four levels are -1.5, -0.5, 0.5 , 1.5 each designated for a frequency tone.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can you please tell me which TED and TED constellation slicer suits best for me? I have put the symbol synch block after Qdemod block, so the input of the symbol synch is exactly that PAM4 signal I described. Which algorithm do you think can work for this type of input? Thank you a lot.